# Is there any way for a sub-grouping to know how many items are in the parent-grouping for a CollectionViewSource in .NET

Tags: .net, grouping, collectionviewsource

I have a Collection View source in which I've set two Group Descriptions

```vb
myCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("PrimaryProperty"))
myCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("SecondaryProperty"))
```

As Illustrated below, the primary grouping has found 338 records.
Those are broken up into 179 pairs of records based on the secondary GroupDescription.  If I'm evaluating a child grouping element, is there a way for me to get the `ItemCount` of the primary grouping from which it originally comes?

[image: View of Groups]

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your local values, you can simply use the following expression

```
((MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal)myCollectionViewSource.View.Groups[0]).ItemCount
```